# Sending code through the clipboard to a remote kernel on IPython

Tags: amazon-web-services, emacs, ssh, ipython, zsh

I often run IPython instances on AWS and be able to send code to it from a terminal. Ideally I would like to do this through the clipboard, i.e. load code in the clipboard and send it to the remote IPython engine.

As an example, in Emacs I often have code in a buffer that I would like to evaluate on a remote IPython kernel.

There seem to be several ways of solving this problem, but none of them have worked for me so far:

### Remote interactive IPython on an ssh session and %paste:

When working locally, I can typically select my text, copy it, and then do `%paste` on the IPython session. This effectively passes the code in the clipboard to the IPython process. However, if I `ssh -X` to a remote machine and start IPython remotely, using `%paste` does not work, I get: `UsageError: The clipboard appears to be empty"`. This probably makes sense since my local machine and the remote machine have different clipboards. I know I can use `%cpaste` to just type code in the terminal, but I am looking for a solution that allows for sharing code through the clipboard.

This takes me to the first question:

- Is there any way to share clipboards between my local machine and the remote IPython?

### Remote Kernel and %paste :

An alternative is would be to start a remote kernel and then connecting to it from  my local machine. To do that, I start the following on the remote machine:

```
$ ipython kernel
To connect another client to this kernel, use --existing kernel-30860.json
```

and  run the following locally, after downloading the json file:

```
$ ipython console --existing kernel-30860.json --<remote_host_address>
```

where `<remote_host_address>` is the adress of the remote machine.

However, when I do the above, the magics `%paste` and `%cpaste` are not enabled, i.e. if I do the following from the local terminal, I get:

```
In [1]: %paste
ERROR: Line magic function `%paste` not found.
```

If I go this route: Is there any way to enable these magics on the client?

### Any other approach?

Aside from the two approaches above, is there any way I could send code from my clipboard to a remote kernel in IPython?

Answer (score 0):

python-mode.el should support this kind of remote execution right from the spot - however not using the clipboard.

In case of trouble a bug report at

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode
```

will be helpful.